# Using timers in microsecond on windows with mingw compiler?

Tags: c++, windows, timer, mingw

I want to set a timer. When the time expires, it should call a callback function. But the time is in microsecond. I find Multimedia timers on windows but i am using mingw compiler on windows. So is there any method using with mingw compiler on windows.

I have tried to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-timer-queues

But i have an error: 'CreateTimerQueue() was not declared in this scope' How do i solve this?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE gDoneEvent;

VOID CALLBACK TimerRoutine(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    if (lpParam == NULL)
    {
        printf("TimerRoutine lpParam is NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // lpParam points to the argument; in this case it is an int

        printf("Timer routine called. Parameter is %d.\n", 
                *(int*)lpParam);
        if(TimerOrWaitFired)
        {
            printf("The wait timed out.\n");
        }
            else
            {
                printf("The wait event was signaled.\n");
            }
        }
    
        SetEvent(gDoneEvent);
    }
    
int main()
{
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    HANDLE hTimerQueue = NULL;
    int arg = 123;

    // Use an event object to track the TimerRoutine execution
    gDoneEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (NULL == gDoneEvent)
    {
        printf("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create the timer queue.
    hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
    if (NULL == hTimerQueue)
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the WinAPI in mingw? If you do, [`SetWaitableTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer) may be useful.

Comment: Actually i do, but when i  use CreateTimerQueue() function, there is an error 'CreateTimerQueue() was not declared in this scope', although i include <windows.h> file. Do you have an idea why this error occurs? @TedLyngmo

Comment: Did you include `threadpoollegacyapiset.h`? Can you get a single timer ([`CreateWaitableTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createwaitabletimerw)) working?

Comment: Also have same error: 'threadpoollegacyapiset.h No such a file or directory'. Is there any macro code to add my code to use WinAPI with Mingw? I googled but i couldnt find the answer. @TedLyngmo

Comment: Can you get a single timer working (not a pool of timers)? Anyway, if you are lacking the header files in your development environment it'll be cumbersome.

Comment: On MinGW you need to include `synchapi.h` for `SetWaitableTimer` and then link with `-lkernel32`.

Comment: I add -lkernel32 and build. There is no error or warning. But when i include synchapi.h there is error: synchapi.h No such a file or directory. @BrechtSanders

Comment: Which version of GCC/MinGW are you using (`gcc --version`)?

Comment: Whatever your goal is, you aren't going to get microsecond precision.

Comment: gcc version is 4.5.2 @BrechtSanders

Comment: @reesu That is a really old version. Can you try with MinGW-w64 GCC 10.2.0? There is a standalone build available from http://winlibs.com/.